# GetCustomAttributes performance issue (expression trees is the solution??)

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, expression-trees

I have a performance problem because I use reflection and GetCustomAttributes for my data access. The performance profiler detected it. I have an extension method like this:

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps DataRow objecto to entity T depending on the defined attributes. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Entity to map.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="rowInstance">DataRow instance.</param>
    /// <returns>Instance to created entity.</returns>
    public static T MapRow<T>(this DataRow rowInstance) where T : class, new()
    {
        //Create T item
        T instance = new T();

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        MappingAttribute map;
        DataColumn column;

        foreach (PropertyInfo item in properties)
        {
            //check if custom attribute exist in this property
            object[] definedAttributes = item.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MappingAttribute), false);

            // Tiene atributos
            if (definedAttributes != null && definedAttributes.Length == 1)
            {
                //recover first attribute
                map = definedAttributes.First() as MappingAttribute;

                column = rowInstance.Table.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
                                          .Where(c => c.ColumnName == map.ColumnName)
                                          .SingleOrDefault();

                if (column != null)
                {
                    object dbValue = rowInstance[column.ColumnName];
                    object valueToSet = null;

                    if (dbValue == DBNull.Value)//if value is null
                        valueToSet = map.DefaultValue;
                    else
                        valueToSet = dbValue;

                    //Set value in property 
                    setValue<T>(instance, item, valueToSet);
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set "item" property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Return entity type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="instance">T type instance</param>
    /// <param name="item">Property name to return value</param>
    /// <param name="valueToSet">Value to set to the property</param>
    private static void setValue<T>(T instance, PropertyInfo item, object valueToSet) where T : class, new()
    {
        if (valueToSet == null)
        {
            CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            if (item.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.ValueType)))
            {
                //if is a value type and is nullable
                if (item.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Nullable"))
                {
                    item.SetValue(instance, null, BindingFlags.Public, null, null, ci);
                }
                else
                {
                    item.SetValue(instance, Activator.CreateInstance(item.PropertyType, null), BindingFlags.Public, null, null, ci);
                }
            }
            else //property type is reference type
            {
                item.SetValue(instance, null, BindingFlags.Public, null, null, ci);
            }
        }
        else // set not null value
        {
            //if is a value type and is nullable
            if (item.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Nullable"))
            {
                item.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(valueToSet, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(item.PropertyType)), null);
            }
            else
            {
                item.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(valueToSet, item.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I do here, in essence, is to map the domain entities with the database fields, and a data helper attacks the tables automatically. An example of one of these entities is:

```
public class ComboBox
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a ComboBox item.
    /// </summary>
    [Mapping("CODE", DefaultValue = 0, DBType = DbParametersTypes.Varchar2, IsKey = true, IdentifierFK = "")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents Text.
    /// </summary>
    [Mapping("DESCRIPTION", DefaultValue = "", DBType = DbParametersTypes.Varchar2, IsKey = false, IdentifierFK = "")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

And the attribute class I use:

```
public sealed class MappingAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }

        public object DefaultValue { get; set; }

        public DbParametersTypes DBType { get; set; }

        public bool IsKey { get; set; }

        public string IdentifierFK { get; set; }

        public bool IsParameter { get; set; } 

        public MappingAttribute(string columnName)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("columnName");

            ColumnName = columnName;
        }               
    }
```

I read [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alon_nativ/archive/2011/01/15/using-expression-trees-to-optimize-your-code.aspx) that a possible improvement could be an expression tree, but, first, I'm not an expression tress expert, and second, I have to solve this with .NET 3.5...(in the sample .NET 4 or 4.5 is used...)

¿Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the bottleneck exactly? Are you caching your maps after you've built them? You could map the index of the property to a cached mapping type so that you don't have to use reflection on successive calls.

Comment: Staring at profiler output can be quite dangerous, it is easy to ignore the cost of the dbase query.  But this is otherwise why ORM tools are popular.  Linq to Sql, Entity Framework, Hibernate, etc.  They calculate the resultset-to-object mapping just one instead of for every single data row.

Comment: The botleneck is in the GetCustomAttributes() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps DataRow objecto to entity T depending on the defined attributes. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Entity to map.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="rowInstance">DataRow instance.</param>
    /// <returns>Instance to created entity.</returns>
    public static T MapRow<T>( this DataRow rowInstance ) where T : class, new()
    {
        //Create T item
        var instance = new T();
        Mapper<T>.MapRow( instance, rowInstance );
        return instance;
    }

    #region Nested type: Mapper

    private static class Mapper<T>
        where T : class
    {
        private static readonly ItemMapper[] __mappers;

        static Mapper()
        {
            __mappers = typeof (T)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where( p => p.IsDefined( typeof (MappingAttribute), false ) )
                .Select( p => new
                {
                    Property = p,
                    Attribute = p
                                  .GetCustomAttributes( typeof (MappingAttribute), false )
                                  .Cast<MappingAttribute>()
                                  .FirstOrDefault()
                } )
                .Select( m => new ItemMapper( m.Property, m.Attribute ) )
                .ToArray();
        }

        public static void MapRow( T instance, DataRow row )
        {
            foreach ( var mapper in __mappers )
            {
                mapper.MapRow( instance, row );
            }
        }

        #region Nested type: ItemMapper

        private sealed class ItemMapper
        {
            private readonly MappingAttribute _attribute;
            private readonly PropertyInfo _property;

            public ItemMapper( PropertyInfo property, MappingAttribute attribute )
            {
                _property = property;
                _attribute = attribute;
            }

            public void MapRow( T instance, DataRow rowInstance )
            {
                //TODO: Implement this with the code already provided
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The first time the extension method is called for a given `<T>`, the static constructor will run and cache an instance `Mapper` for each property that has a `MappingAttribute` attached.  Then, for every call after that, it will used the cached mappers to do the actual copy.

You can also make `Mapper` abstract, and use a different subclass for each branch in your `setValue<T>()`.  That way most of your reflection only happens once.

Comment: Thanks James. I have rewrited your code (to compile it. Else I can't test it) and something has to be wrong when correcting it, because the performance tests are worst than the old MapRow...

Comment: I think I have found the mistake!! As I imagined, I have implemented incorrectly the last MapRow(T instance, DataRow rowInstance) method...I have test it and the improvement has been great (89% less time) Thank you!